# Using the definite article

Tags: articles, definite-article

We usually use the for nouns (or words that act as nouns) that are specific/known.
For example:
*The boy.

The movie (we watched).*

Here *the* refers to the nouns *boy* & *movie* respectively. 
But what about the situation where there an adjective is between the definite article and the noun, like:

*The nice boy.

The interesting movie.*

Here, to what word does the definite article refer, to *boy* or *nice* or the construct *nice boy*, and to *interesting* or *movie* or both?

That is, I meant, what word is specific/known in these sentences that we used the definite article for them?

Comment: *Nice boy* and *interesting movie* is a noun phrase. Nice and interesting are adjuncts that modify the main nouns boy and movie.

Comment: The rule you are relying is not quite accurate. It should be "use *the* for a noun or a noun phrase"

Comment: I agree; the articles determine a noun phrase, whether it be a noun alone as in _Hand me the screwdriver_ or a noun with dependents as in _Pass me the tall ladder_.

Comment: Thank you all for the useful comments. So in my sentences, the article refers to the construct or as you say, the noun phrases. That is, that noun phrase is known/specific.

Comment: @franky yes, you are right!